# About to be knocked out, all in

Tags: all-in, side-pots

I’m about to be knocked out and call all in. There are still 2 players who are able to bet/raise for a side pot, do I immediately have to reveal my hand because I called all in or do I wait until the other players finish their betting? I assume waiting until they finish betting because they could make decisions based on what my hand is even though I’m no longer contributing to the pot(?)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you wait. Nobody should never reveal their hand, or any part of it, until no more betting can take place, for exactly the reason you state - it could easily influence the other players' action if they know your hand.